# how to make a cookie last a year PHP

Tags: php, cookies

I attempted to make a cookie-based theme switcher using PHP, and to make the cookie I use this:

```
$t = $_GET["t"];
if($t == "dark" || "light" || "mixed") {
    setcookie("theme", $t, time() + 31556926, "/");
} elseif(!isset($t) and !isset($_COOKIE["theme"])) {
    setcookie("theme", "dark", time() + 31556926 , "/");
}
if(isset($_COOKIE["theme"])) {
    echo "<body style=\"background:url(/imgs/" . $_COOKIE['theme'] . ".gif) top left repeat\">";
} else {
    echo "<body style=\"background:url(/imgs/dark.gif) top left repeat\">";
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work, it reloads the page and sets the cookie, but has a strange property of needing to reload the page **again** in order for it to change the background, and only lasting for the session. As well as this, when you return to the index.php without `?t=light` it stays, but then when you reload it disappears. I couldn't figure out any reason that it should be acting this way.

Comment: please, provide some context and the code you use to change the background

Comment: Do you have any code above these two lines?

Comment: After setting the cookie you have to `reload` or `redirect` as you can read it in the [description of setcookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

Comment: setcookie("theme", $t, time()+ 60,'/'); // expires after 60 seconds

Comment: Is your cookie set properly?

Comment: print_r($_COOKIE);    //output the contents of the cookie array variable

Comment: what is the output of `$_COOKIE` variable?

Comment: My question is still not answered. Do you have any code above the code we see here?

Comment: @Avishake I assume you mean what `$_COOKIE["theme"]` is equal to, and the answer to that would be _usually_ what is after ?t= in the url. the reason I say "usually" is because even when you've gone from ?t=dark after being on ?t=light, until you reload, `$_COOKIE["theme]"` is still "dark"

Comment: @Andreas That is all of the PHP code, everything else on the page is CSS, HTML, and JS

Comment: @Beaux so there is nothing above. No HTML, no CSS and no JavaScript? You didn't really answer

Comment: @Andreas oh, well above it is the head, and in it some CSS, but nothing else

Comment: Thank you. And that is your problem. I will post an answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you have syntax errors..Just try it..

```
$t = $_GET["t"];
if($t == "dark" || $t ==  "light" || $t == "mixed") {
     setcookie("theme", $t, time() + 31556926, "/");
 } elseif(!isset($t) && !isset($_COOKIE["theme"])) {
     setcookie("theme", "dark", time() + 31556926 , "/");
 }
if(isset($_COOKIE["theme"])) {
 echo "<body style=\"background:url(/imgs/" . $_COOKIE['theme'] . ".gif) top  left repeat\">";
} else {
echo "<body style=\"background:url(/imgs/dark.gif) top left repeat\">";
}
```

Comment: I hadn't thought this would've been part of the problem as it still set the cookie, but this fixed the cookie being deleted at the end of the session, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make your life easier using [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

```
setcookie('theme', 'dark', strtotime('+1 year'), '/');
```

By the way, cookies should be above everything else - it's part of the header. You should place it above all, else - it may produce errors (if you want to hide the errors you can simply insert `@` before `setcookie`).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a maximum, however I found a couple of people who suggest it is limited by the unixtime, ie nothing past 2038.  However, as others have pointed out, there is no point making it more than 10 years as browsers / computers will expire within 10 years and be reloading or replaced etc.  My reference:
https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-limit-to-a-persistent-cookies-expiry-date

In the meantime I found this regarding the size and number limits:
http://browsercookielimits.iain.guru/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you, as you said in comments have the setcookie below other code.

You can not have any output before the setcookie.
Move the code you have in the question as far up as you can.

See here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

> If output exists prior to calling this function, setcookie() will fail and return FALSE.

Edit; and with as far up as possible, I mean above `<HTML>` tag

Edit2; about the isset.

```
If(isset($_GET["t"])){
      $t = $_GET["t"];
}Else{
      $t = "dark";
}
if($t == "dark" || "light" || "mixed") {
    setcookie("theme", $t, time() + 31556926, "/");
} elseif(!isset($t) and !isset($_COOKIE["theme"])) {
    setcookie("theme", "dark", time() + 31556926 , "/");
 }
if(isset($_COOKIE["theme"])) {
    echo "<body style=\"background:url(/imgs/" . $_COOKIE['theme'] . ".gif) top left repeat\">";
} else {
     echo "<body style=\"background:url(/imgs/dark.gif) top left repeat\">";
}
```

It's hard to get it right on phone but you get the idea.

Comment: This didn't seem to have any effect, but thanks for the information.

Comment: @Beaux Maybe it's because you test against $t that may or may not be set. If it's not set you end up with a php warning, output, and that makes the setcookie fail? Try to first check with isset() against  $_GET["t"] and if that is false set the dark theme.

Comment: I had noticed that doing this allows me to get rid of the final else statement, and I had put it above the `<html>` which didn't have an effect, you then edited your answer, so I tried putting it above the doctype, which also had no effect.

Comment: @Beaux copy only the part of the code with setcookie and background to a new empty php file and test it there. Also do you have the body style at the correct place? I guess that is supposed to be in body and not above HTML. When I wrote "move up", I didn't mean you should move the body as it's part of the HTML.

Comment: I split it in to 2 `<?php?>` blocks, so the part where it sets the cookie is at the top, and where it echoes the body tag stayed in the same place.

Comment: @Beaux Nothing? That didn't work either? What about in a new file?

Comment: Do you have errors off? Try to enable errors: error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

Comment: I'm quite sure it's a output before header error you got. Even a single space is enough to fail the setcookie. For example `<?php ` <- with a space after the tag is enough to fail setcookie.

Comment: Btw, it seems to have been that `if($t == "dark" || "light" || "mixed")` didn't work correctly, as Jana pointed out in their answer. So I tried `if($t == "dark" || $t ==  "light" || $t == "mixed")` and that worked. The problem I have now is that the user needs to manually reload the page, which is already automatically done, for the background change to actually take affect. Edit: I'm not entirely sure how the `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1);` line of code actually works, but I tried adding it to see what it would do, and it just made the window blank.

Comment: That part works https://3v4l.org/atCDE but you can not get around the fact that you need to reload or pass the user to a new page after setcookie. You can set the cookie and force the page to reload with meta, or have a separate page just for setting cookies/or settings as it seems you use them for.

Comment: If error reporting makes your page blank you have some serious problems with coding. It's supposed to give you error messages on screen if there is any. Also. Looking at your profile you have four questions, no accepted answers and no vote casts. I think it's time you give back to people what they have given you.

Comment: @Beaux you could take the tout and receive the informed badge. https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2600/informed